# Easier way to map record names for a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I am currently using the `REPLACE` function to change a couple record names (ints to their corresponding human readable name) like this:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT) AS Actions, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(EVENT, 2, 'iOS'), 1, 'Web'), 3, 'Android'), 4, 'Windows'), 5, 'Mac'), 6, 'Unknown') AS Platform 
FROM `METRICS_WEEKLY` 
WHERE EVENT IN (1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6) 
GROUP BY EVENT
```

I would like to build a query which is using more than 30 numbers in the the `EVENT` column and map them to friendlier names. I am unable to alter the current table (I am not the creator of the table schema). Is there an easier way to map a larger group of field names?

Comment: I just want to say that the use of `replace` is quite clever, in a certain fashion, because the Event is probably stored as an integer.  I would never have thought of doing it this way.

Comment: You better use foreign keys. Scalable and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT) AS Actions, 
        (CASE event 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Web' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'iOS' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Android'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Windows' 
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Mac' 
        ELSE 'Unknown' END )  AS Platform
FROM METRICS_WEEKLY
WHERE EVENT IN (1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6) 
GROUP BY EVENT
```

Comment: Not very feasible if there will be more values to add or change.

Comment: Than you can create a table which specify all events in that. You can easily join that table with this and it will be good to do that

Comment: @SaharshShah . . . Using a `case` statement is a very reasonable solution.  It would be clearer, though, if you formatted your query to make it readable.  I still prefer my solution (use of a subquery), because it easily allows other columns to be included, columns that might prove useful for other purposes.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution since I can't create or alter the current table. I will try this out. With some formatting and carriage returns I think it would be more readable.

Comment: @andyshinn check my updated answer. I also added end keyword to end the case statement

Comment: I found this to be the easiest stopgap measure until I can implement a more elegant solution like one of the other answers. This is based on me currently not able to change the app spec (can't update schema or add tables). Gordon's answer was also an acceptable working solution. But this reads a little simpler without needing more complex INNER JOINS. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the [`ENUM` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).  Create the column as an `ENUM` of your list, and you avoid all the string replacements.  The values will be stored in their integer formats and *must* be one of the available choices, but will display as their string equivalents.

```
CREATE TABLE `METRICS_WEEKLY` (
  `COUNT` INT,
  `EVENT` ENUM (
    'Web',
    'iOs',
    'Android',
    'Windows'
    'Mac',
    'Unknown'
  )
);
```

Alternatively if the list is short, create a table to hold these values according to proper normalization.

Comment: This is a really good idea (and I did not know about the ENUM type). But I cannot alter the table or create additional tables at the moment. I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: @AndyShinn Use njk's table relationship then.  (actually that is what I would do in this situation rather than ENUM)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use a mapping table.

```
ReplaceValue
---------------
value    number
iOS      2
Web      1
Android  3
Windows  4
```

Then `JOIN` on the `value` and use `number`. You may want to consider creating a relationship so that if you update the values to be replaced, they will cascade to the child table.

Comment: This, rather than my `ENUM`, is probably the _right_ solution here.

Comment: This is probably a sound solution too. Unfortunately, I cannot add or update tables at this time (I have to use what the current application gives me). I appreciate the answer though and will consider implementing something like this when given the chance.

Answer (score 1):

You really, really, really want an EventType reference table.  In the meantime, something like this:

```
select EventName, COUNT(*) as Actions
from Metrics_Weekly mw left outer join
     (select 'iOS' as EventName, 2 as EventId union all
      select 'Web', 1 union all
      select 'Android', 3 union all
      select 'Window', 4 union all
      select 'Mac', 5 union all
      select 'Unknown', 6
     ) eventType
     on mw.Event = evenType.eventId
group by eventName
```

Comment: So far this looks like the best solution since I can't add or alter tables. I am testing this out. Thanks for this elaborate solution. I am amazed at the fast response for SQL questions.